# Jabber-net Register New User

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xmpp, chat

I am new to jabber and xmpp. I am developing Chat client application using c#, wpf and jabber-net. I have created Register Form but i got some error in Code behind.

```
jc.OnRegisterInfo += new RegisterInfoHandler(this.jc_OnRegisterInfo);
jc.OnRegistered += new IQHandler(jc_OnRegistered);
```

No overload for 'jc_OnRegistered' matches delegate 'jabber.client.IQHandler'

No overload for 'jc_OnRegisterInfo' matches delegate 'jabber.client.RegisterInfoHandler'

Thanks in advances...

Answer (score 1):

The `OnRegisterInfo` event is a `RegisterInfoHandler` which is declared as:

```
public delegate bool RegisterInfoHandler(Object sender, Register register);
```

You must have a method that returns `bool`, and takes an `object` as a first parameter, and a `Register` as a second parameter.

The `OnRegistered` event is an `IQHandler` which is declared as:

```
public delegate void IQHandler(Object sender, IQ iq);
```

You must have a method that returns `void`, and takes an `object` as a first parameter, and an `IQ` as a second parameter.

Make sure that `jc_OnRegisterInfo` looks like this:

```
private bool jc_OnRegisterInfo(object sender, Register register)
{
    // ...
}
```

and `jc_OnRegistered` looks like this:

```
private void jc_OnRegistered(object sender, IQ iq)
{
    // ...
}
```